# Hide/Show not working in JSP?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have the following code in my JSP. Hide/Show is not working.. Where am I going wrong?
JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#hide").click(function(){
       $("pageNav").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
     $("pageNav").show();
    });
 });
</script>
```

JSP:

```
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<div id="pageNav">
    <div class="sidebarmenu">
        <ul>
             <li>......</li>
             <li>......</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Default button type is submit as far as I remember, so clicking it will reload the page. Add `type="button"` to both buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be selected with `#` since it is an `id` and also use `.on()` like

```
$('#pageNav').hide();
```

Then your code will be

```
$("#hide").on('click',function(){
    $("#pageNav").css('display','none');  // $('#pageNav').hide();
});
$("#show").on('click',function(){
    $("#pageNav").css('display','block');  // $('#pageNav').show();
});
```

And my doubt is ....if you hide the `pageNav` then where you will click to show it..?? May be you need to put those buttons **outside** of the `pageNav`.

Comment: thanks.... How can I show it on mousehover? I mean, by default, the div is hidden and will be shown only on mouseHover..

Comment: Add the mouseover and mouseleave actions on the menu `sidebarmenu` and display : block when mouseover and mouseleave display : none